# Lambda Expression to get records from list in a list

Tags: list, lambda

I have a class as following:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public Wrapper();

    public Class1 c1 { get; set; }
    public List<Class2> lstC2 { get; set; }
}
```

where Class2 is :

```
 public class Class2
{
    public DateTime date1 { get; set; }
}
```

and I get the list of objects of Wrapper class by some method

```
     List<Wrapper> lstWrap = SomeMethod();
```

Now I want to remove All the records from lstWrap where date1 is less than today for any record in lstC2 using lambda expression. I tried using **RemoveAll** function but could not meet the results.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in these situations I would use .All() or .Any()

```
var lts = new List<Wrapper>();
var res  = lts.Where (l => l.lstC2.All(d => d.date1 >= DateTime.Now));
```

EDIT:

To remove all I would still use the .Any()

```
lstWrap.RemoveAll(l => l.lstC2.Any(a => a.date1 < DateTime.Now));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete the item with at least one date which less than today,use:

```
 lstWrap.RemoveAll(l=>l.lstC2.Count(d=>d.date1<DateTime.Today)>0);
```